# XMLHttpRequest Not Sending

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

This is part of the code for the extension:

```
let url = "https://mywebsite.com/data.php";
function newRequest() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("POST", url, true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    client.send("status=true");
    console.log(client.status);
}
newRequest();
```

Which also logs 0 in the console. I've been following the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest, trying countless tweaks, and there aren't any errors in the console. Not really sure what the issue could be.

The PHP on my server definitely works since I was able to POST the data successfully from a local html file.

Answer (score 0):

Since the AJAX request is asynchronous, you need to handle it through a callback `onreadystatechange`.

The code should be like this

```
let url = "https://mywebsite.com/data.php";
function newRequest() {
    var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(this.readyState) // should be 4
        console.log(this.status) // should be 200 OK
        console.log(this.responseText) // response return from request
    };
    client.open("POST", url, true);
    client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
    client.send("status=true");
    console.log(client.status);
}
newRequest();
```

Hope this helps.

**For More Info:** https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp